# Struts2 Java Util date conversion problem

Tags: java, struts2

In my application i have one textfield which maps to date in action class. If i entered 15/12/2011 (MM/dd/yyyy) it automatically converts it to 03/12/2012(MM/dd/yyyy).

My code is :

jsp Page :

```
<s:textfield name="drDt" id="drDt" />
```

Action class:

```
private Date drDt;
public Date getDrDt() {
    return drDt;
}

public void setDrDt(Date drDt) {
    this.drDt = drDt;
}
```

Problem is with code :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

sdf.parse(dateValue);
```

above statement has some problem.

Comment: that is how SimpleDateFormat handles some invalid dates. It passes extra hours into days, extra days into months and extra months into years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "default" behaviour. Otherwise, set [`dateFormat.setLenient()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to `false`. Setting that to `false` will throw `Exception` upon encountering invalid date like the one in your example. You need to handle that gracefully. Perhaps, show a message to the user that the date entered is not correct or invalid. Precisely, add validator to validate user inputs.

Comment: @jaychapani: There must be some conversion going on somewhere. Try to look for that or wait.... I am on it.

Comment: after setting dateFormat.setLenient() to false it throws : **java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15/12/2011"** exveption.

Comment: public class MyDateConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter{
@Override
public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) throws TypeConversionException {
 try{
        if (values == null || values.length == 0 || CelticStringUtil.isBlank(values[0])) {
             return null;
         }
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        return sdf.parse(values[0]);
 }catch(Exception e){
  logger.fatal("Exception in CmvsDateConverter.convertFromString: " + e.getMessage(), e);
  throw new TypeConversionException(e);
 }
}}

Comment: @jaychapani: Yes, indeed it will do that. Now handle it gracefully. Show a message to the user that the date entered is not correct or invalid. Precisely, add validator to validate user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

MM/dd/yyyy is Month / day / year. 
You wrote 15/12/2011, that is Month 15 = (15 - 12 ) =3 / day 12 and years + 1 (2011 + the extra year from 15) as 15 is an invalid month.
Try switching to dd/MM/yyyy